# For Each Sheet in Workbook.sheets - but in Reverse?

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I was using `For Each sheet In .Worksheets` for automating a report...and finally realized why the numbers on the first couple of sheets were off...they pull from later sheets.

However, the order the sheets are in needs to be preserved, or at least restored, because this is how management uses them.  If I could go in reverse order while entering data, there shouldn't be a problem with sheet references.

Is there a way to do `For Each sheet in .Worksheets Step -1` ??

Or would I need to move the sheets around...loop through, enter data, run calcs...then move sheets back?  Or use the Index and loop backwards?  Any suggestions?

Comment: `For Each` only goes in one direction. If you need to reverse, then use `For` with `Step -1`.

Comment: I would just say use `For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1` and then just reference each sheet as `Sheets(i)`. This probably isn't what you're looking for but it's easier than reversing the order of the sheets to use a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Note, when iterating collection of objects, `For Each` performs better than `For...Next`. `Worksheets` is one such object collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub LoopSheetsBackwards()

Dim i As Long

For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name ' <--for debug - show sheet name
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: A Reverse For Each would be easier, but this works just fine for what I need, thanks.

Comment: @Rdster I've never seen a "reverse for each" loop in any language.

Comment: Me either, but that doesn't mean I wasn't being hopeful that I just didn't know about it.  I would think being able to go forward or backward through a collection would be handy enough that it would have been implemented somewhere....but I guess not.